# Why high autocorrelation implies predictability?

Tags: forecasting, autocorrelation

I dont understand this point for h-steps ahead forecasts.

Even if I know that the $t+2, t+3, ..., t+h$ forecasts are highly autocorrelated, I dont really know if this autocorrelation is not just right, as I need $h$ steps ahead to evaluate it...

Nor?

Comment: Please rephrase your question to make more sense. Also, please don't use double-negatives.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but I think this may answer it:

$t+h$ is just a short hand way of denoting the $h^{\text{th}}$ lag rather than writing out long hand all the predictors for $Y$. For example, if you have monthly data and seasonality is important then you will may want $t-12$ as a predictor in your time series (in which case h=12), you may even want $t-24$ and $t-36$.